# Why is the plot like that?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I have tried to plot the following function's level curves by hand and then checked my drawing with wolfram alphas level curve applet and I don't understand why it only plots the left half?
In my drawing it is a parabola?

$$z=x+5*\sqrt y$$

EDIT:

[Wolfram Alpha Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHu76.png)

[My Expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XGo7.jpg)

Comment: $\sqrt{y}$ is not defined for negative $y$.

Comment: okay so here I will show you how I calculated: I took an arbitrary level, for example z=2. Now if I check what value y would have if I take for example x=3. It will be 1/25, right? I am confused.. In the wolfram alpha plot the graph stops at x=2 :( and I don't understand why

Comment: Please post the images of the Wolframalpha plot and the plot you expect.

Comment: I've posted the pictures in my edited question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to what other comment say, the reason is not $\sqrt y$ being undefined for negative $y$. The reason is that $\sqrt y$ is a positive number and you are missing the half-parabola $$z=x-5\sqrt y.$$

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on that please?

Comment: @Maria: there is nothing more to say. Plug values in the equation to convince yourself.

Comment: Oh so you mean we only have the left side of the parabola because there is a plus? Hm

Comment: @Maria: exactly. So you don't get the full parabola $25y=(z-x)^2$, only the half with $x<z$.

Comment: Okay, so I feel like I kind of understood it, but when I do the math I don't understand why I still find a point: Look at my calculations: $y=\frac{(2-x)^2}{25}$ . So suppose I don't know anything about the form of this function and I want to know the y value for x=3, so I insert it into the equation and I get  $y=\frac{(2-3)^2}{25}=0,04$ . I do understand that I make a mistake somewhere but I don't understand where...

Comment: @Maria: $2-3$ is negative, isn't it ?

Comment: yes, so why should that be a problem? It is squared anyway? Please excuse my stupidity :(

Comment: @Maria: it doesn't fulfill the initial equation.